# Assistance in Understanding Comparing the Difference Between two Unix Timestamps in PHP

Tags: php, math, unix-timestamp

I don't want to call this an error because I'm unsure if I am just missing something here...

Here is the code:

```
$difference_in_hours = abs($current_timestamp - intval($_REQUEST['timestamp'])) / 3600;
```

The idea is to give a timestamp, and compare against the current time (in hours). After that, the idea is to utilize something like this:

```
if ($difference_in_hours > 12) { //do something... }
```

The issue I am running into is if I utilize a current timestamp of say "1568259496" and then input "1568314800" which is under 12 hours apart, the math comes out to "15.3494444444" however, I know that these two times are under 12 hours a part.

Could somebody help me understand where I am going wrong? I feel like this should be simple.

Comment: Those two timestamps are _not_ under 12 hours apart! See https://3v4l.org/j903m. The math you're getting is correct.

Comment: New link that uses DateTime::diff to provide hours/minutes apartL https://3v4l.org/fN6SF

Comment: `date -d @1568259496` -> `2019年09月12日 11:38:16`; `date -d @1568314800` -> `2019年09月13日  3:00:00` clearly it's not under 12 hour.

Comment: Okay, I see where I went wrong. Complete error in evaluating in UTC time and mixing up the timestamp. I understand my error. So when I evaluate timestamps moments apart such as this: Current: 1568260457 Input: 1568260433 the output reads: 435627.904722 which is over 12, even though they are under 12 hours apart

Comment: @user3259138 Eh? 1568260457 and 1568260433 are only 12 seconds apart. And your own code returns a tine fraction of an hour, see here: https://3v4l.org/vWhgR. You're messing up somewhere else.